# How to deploy by stage with Chalice using CDK

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, chalice

I can't find any examples of how to deploy by stages (environments) when deploying a Chalice app with CDK, as spelled out here? https://aws.github.io/chalice/tutorials/cdk.html

I found https://aws.github.io/chalice/topics/stages.html, but can't find any reference to CDK.

What I want to do is deploy two different cloud formation stacks, pivoting by stage. I'd like a `dev` cf stack, as well as a `prod` stack. Each should have the same shape for their resources, but of course each resource should be distinct and namespaced according to stage.

Comment: Have you found out how to do this?

Comment: I'm doing it like this https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/1719#issuecomment-988414731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with an example app like follows:

```py
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from stacks.vpc_stack import VpcStack
from stacks.rds_stack import RdsStack
from stacks.chalice_stack import ChaliceStack

app = cdk.App()
vpc_stack = VpcStack(app, 'vpc-cdk')
rds_stack = RdsStack(app, 'rds-cdk', vpc_stack.vpc)
chalice = ChaliceStack(app, 'chalice-cdk', rds_stack.rds_db)

app.synth()
```

from the command line you can deploy selectively like this:

```
cdk deploy chalice-cdk
```